# The "Aapt" task could not be instantiated

Tags: c#, xamarin, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an application using `Xamarin.Forms` using Xamarin with Visual Studio; after building my solution, it is showing me some messages regarding `AndroidManifest.xml` and errors.

**Messages:**

1. `Could not find schema information for the element 'application'`
2. `Could not find schema information for the element 'manifest'`
3. `Could not find schema information for the element 'uses-sdk'`

**Errors:**

1. `The "Aapt" task could not be instantiated from "C:\Program Files (x86) \MSBuild \Xamarin\Android \Xamarin.Android.Build.Tasks.dll".`
2. `The "Aapt" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and the assembly name.`

I use VS2015, help me please to solve this issue.

Comment: Please, post the relevant part of your code.

Comment: @il_raffa This error is not occur because of my coding. Something is going wrong related to sdk because i got this error after updating my sdk version before updating it my code was working fine.

Comment: You should contact Xamarin Support or Forum. This is not really a programming question that could be answered here. As a work around you can try using the Xamarin.Studio and see if this works in it.